# How to see someone's profile icon without the hat on?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015, profile-picture

"You can leave your hat on" said the song.

However is it possible to see someone's profile icon without the <s>mask</s> hat on? I mean, without "opting out" of course.

Currently I'm using Chrome dev tools to remove the "hat layer"...

Not that this is something I need to do all the time :-) Sometimes...

Comment: Inspect and remove element...no other way.

Comment: You can turn off hats by clicking the snowflake at the top and then hitting 'I hate hats'. Then turn it back on when you're done.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no programmed feature... hmmm why the super down voting, am I the only one on Earth interested with this feature?

Comment: No, it's more likely because you couldn't possibly have missed it on Stack Overflow where you're expected to opt in first before being able to opt out.

Comment: @BoltClock I see. Question edited.

Comment: Or just open their profile in an incognito window.

Comment: @MartinSmith that's clever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best answer based on comments seems to be from @MartinSmith.

Since there is no quick feature to hide the "hat" from a profile, without the 'I hate hats' (which I don't) opting-out, just

> open the user's profile in an incognito window

Which is just a right-click away..